# How to keep state of a a property in a object with vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I’m trying to figure out how to approach this in the best way. I got a page that contains the following data

```
data() {
    return {
      game: {
        ball: {
          name: "",
          date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
        },
        selectedPlayerIds: []
      }
    };
  }
```

On this page the user can start to play a game. On the same page I have a component that can add a player. The addPlayer function is in my Vuex player store. My wonder here is how would I update the selectedPlayerIds or have it to be Vuex state and still a part of game object.

One thought I had was to have the selectedPlayerIds outside of the game object and merge the two on save (saveGame).

```
addGame(store, payload) {
  // do merge of objects here
  // payload.game and payload.selectedPlayerIds

  axios
    .post("http://localhost:3000/game", mergedGame)
    .then(response => {
        // do something
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // log error
    });
}
```

But thinking about it, even when I load the game users will be able to modify it like adding/removing players so I’m stuck in the same thing.

What are your thoughts on this? What are my options? What would be the most “correct way”?

Comment: so the problem is that `selectedPlayerIds` is a Vuex state, but you also want it to be a property of  `game` state, is that right?

Comment: @JacobGoh Yea you could say that. It is a property of `game` but I would like it to be a Vuex state as well. Maybe I'm going all wrong about this part of Vue and Vuex?

Comment: If a state is going to be used between multiple components, use Vuex. If it's only used by 1 component, use component local state. You know your app architecture better to judge which one to use =]

Comment: @JacobGoh I got that part figured :) It's used across multiple components. I'm trying to figure if I should save `game` to Vuex or if I actually can just have a property saved in Vuex but still be a part of `game`?

Comment: `can just have a property saved in Vuex but still be a part of game` can be done using computed properties. I can write an answer if that's what you are after.

Comment: @JacobGoh sure if it's a more complete answer regarding it being a part of `game`. Thanks